# `nobody:nobody` and `www:www` all do not support the Smarty project

Tags: macos, phpstorm, smarty

I follow a tutorial of Smarty:

```
chown nobody:nobody /web/www.example.com/guestbook/templates_c/
chmod 770 /web/www.example.com/guestbook/templates_c/

chown nobody:nobody /web/www.example.com/guestbook/cache/
chmod 770 /web/www.example.com/guestbook/cache/
```

On my Mac I've tried to use `chown nobody:nobody` and `chown www:www` to my project's `templates_c` and `cache`.

But PhpStorm still have no permission to access them:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Those permissions don't make much sense. What tutorial are you following?

Answer (score 0):

Although probably not recommended, you could `chmod 777` those folders - effectively giving everyone full permissions including yourself (and phpstorm).